# Why is my method not found by the compiler?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class "Worker" with an entry method

```
internal void Run()
{
//do stuff...
}
```

I have a subclass for testing  ("TestWorker:Worker") with an entry method

```
internal void Run(object aParam)
{
//do something with aParam, then..
Run();
}
```

I have a test app which launches an instance of TestWorker in a new thread,

```
        Worker worker;
        Thread workerThread;
...
        worker = new TestWorker();
        workerThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(worker.Run));
        workerThread.Start("something");
```

This won't compile, and the compiler reports that the parameterized delegate (in my subclass) cannot be found.
I can overcome the problem by declaring a dummy virtual Run(object) method in my Worker class such that my TestWorker.Run(object) overrides it but IMHO it is an inelegant solution, so why do I have to do this? Is it a compiler idiosyncrasy, or am I doing something logically incorrect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the compile-time type of `worker` is just `Worker` - and there *isn't* a `Worker.Run` method accepting a parameter.

This has nothing to do with delegates per se - you wouldn't be able to call

```
worker.Run("foo");
```

either. The simplest way to fix this is just to change the declaration of `worker` to be `TestWorker`. Alternatively, use a separate local variable:

```
TestWorker testWorker = new TestWorker();
workerThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(testWorker.Run));
worker = testWorker;
```

Comment: I did try changing the declaration but repeatedly got the same error when building the solution- hence my question. However I have found that by explicitly cleaning the project and rebuilding it all, the error has disappeared. Maybe it's a VS2008 quirk.

Comment: @NeilHaughton: Why didn't you *mention* that in the question? It should be fine - please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. I'll simultaneously come up with one which shows it working :)

Comment: @NeilHaughton: Given that you've now accepted the answer, presumably you've found it works after all, and you'd got a different problem?

Comment: Because when I asked the question I had not yet thought of or tried that particular approach. After asking the question I thought 'hang on what about', tried it, and got the same error, so simply assumed it was not the answer. When you proposed it I tried again and persevered, with the result I describe. Why did I not give a full code example? Because it would have been a lot of code, so I distilled it down to the essentials to describe the problem. But thanks for your input, which I appreciate.

Comment: Replies are crossing here and it's getting confusing. Yes your answer solved the problem once I had cleaned the solution and completely rebuilt it. No longer any problem.

Comment: @NeilHaughton: It really *doesn't* need to be a lot of code. I've reproduced the problem and the solution in a 22-line complete program. Additionally, if you only thought of changing the declaration *after* asking the question, it's not clear what "hence my question" meant in your first comment. I took it to mean that you'd already tried it, not found a solution, and therefore you asked the question. Even if that's not the case, it's always worth editing the question as you gain more information and try other things.